# Makefile pattern rule with variable in target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using Gnu Make 3.81, and getting an error trying to match a pattern rule that also has a variable in it.

Here's the smallest example I could come up with:

```
YYMMDD:=$(shell date +%y%m%d)
TMP_DIR:=/tmp/$(YYMMDD)

# create a temporary directory, and put a "source" file in it
$(TMP_DIR):
    mkdir $(TMP_DIR)
    echo something > $(TMP_DIR)/somefile.orig

# to build an "object" file in the temp dir, process the "source" file
$(TMP_DIR)/%.new: $(TMP_DIR)/%.orig
    wc -l $< > $@

atarget: $(TMP_DIR) $(TMP_DIR)/somefile.new
```

Then when I run `make atarget`, I get:

```
mkdir /tmp/141021
echo something > /tmp/141021/somefile.orig
make: *** No rule to make target `/tmp/141021/somefile.new', needed by `atarget'.  Stop.
```

Shouldn't this work?  it seems like the pattern rule should match this just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's because make doesn't know that the `.orig` file exists: you have a rule that builds `$(TMP_DIR)` but make doesn't know that this rule also builds `$(TMP_DIR)/somefile.orig`.  So when make is trying to match the pattern rule it will see that the `.orig` file doesn't exist and it doesn't have any way that it knows how to make that file, so the pattern doesn't match, and after that there's no way to build the `.new` file.

You should write:

```
$(TMP_DIR)/%.orig:
        mkdir -p $(TMP_DIR)
        echo $* > $@
```

then it will work.

Comment: I guess there's something I don't understand then.  Why wouldn't make just check to see that the ".orig" file actually exists?

Comment: Make has a cache of which files exist, for performance reasons.  The cache is updated when make knows that some file has been created.  In this case no rule has been run that says it will create that file.  Also, note that your makefile is invalid if you enabled parallelism (`-j`), since make would then start building `$(TMP_DIR)` then immediately start trying to find the next target, which it couldn't find since the command to build `$(TMP_DIR)` was not finished.  In general it's just a bad idea to rely on "side-effects" of rules rather than explicit prerequisites.

Comment: If that's true, why does a default "%.o: %.c" rule work?

Comment: It wouldn't work (reliably), if the `.c` file was created as a side-effect of another rule that didn't list the `.c` file as a target that the rule would build.  That's what you're doing here: listing `$(TMP_DIR)` as the target to be built, but actually building an extra file `$(TMP_DIR)/somefile.orig` and using that as a prerequisite for another target..